# How to create UserControl without a panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I would like to create myself a `UserControl`, that would behave like `Timer` or `FileSystemWatcher`. That means it has no visual component, no `Panel` or such.

But when I use `Visual Studio 2013 **for Windows Desktop**` to create `UserControl` it starts with a panel for me to add things.

[timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J34y4.gif)

I see no `Component` object that I could use in the `Add item` menu:

[available objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs84J.gif)

Comment: A Component is not a UserControl.  Beyond the vast difference in the classes, the most obvious difference is that it doesn't have a visual surface, it is just code.

Comment: Thanks. How can I then adapt a class to be supported in the designer?

Comment: Derive from the Component class instead.  The easiest way to get started is with Project > Add New Item > Component Class.  The design surface you get is very rarely useful so immediately click the "switch to code view" link.  Public properties you add with a getter and setter will be editable in the Properties window.

Comment: Unfortunately I see no Component Class in Add New item menu... Can it be possibly because of I use "lite" for Windows Desktop version?

Comment: Isn't from `control` that you should inherit ?

Comment: @Martin : Not if he wants it to behave like a Timer does in the designer. Component is the correct choice for that.

Comment: @Gerren : Even though you don't see the component in the item menu you can still make one. Create a new class instead and put `Inherits Component` below the `Public Class` line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your file should look like then (in Visual Studio, just say "Add new Class"):

```
Public Class MyComponent
    Inherits Component

    Public Property MyProperty As Boolean
    Public Property MySecondProperty As Boolean

    Public Function MyMethod() As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

If you compile your project, then you might see the `MyComponent` in the designer